# Hmm, a thoughtful library

Tags: javascript, search, query-selector

I've been writing far too many routines in JavaScript that get a record from a an object or array based off a matching property, much like jQuery does with DOM elements. Since all the good names are taken, I called it `Hmm`.

I went with the philosophy that if I don't need it yet, I wont provide for it.

```
var Hmm = (function()
{ //A snippet/library to find records in table-like JS arrays

  function getNamedValue( o , name  )
  { //Name can have dots, 'car.tire.brand.name' should get the expected
    var parts = name.split(".");
    while( parts.length && o ){
      o = o[parts.shift()];    
    }
    return o;
  }  

  function unique( )
  { //Assuming `this` is an array, will copy all unique entries of `this` to a returned new array
    var array = [], map = {}, json;
    this.forEach( function( value ){
      if( value instanceof Object ){
        json = JSON.stringify( value );
        if( !map[json] ){
          array.push( value );
          map[json] = true;
        }
      }
      else if( !~array.indexOf( value ) ){
        array.push( value );
      }
    });
    return array;
  }  

  function Hmm( data )
  { //data could be a string -> treat as JSON, parse it
    //data could be an object, or a string that got converted to an object -> convert to array
    //data could be an array ( original or through conversion ) -> leave as is
    this.data = data instanceof Object ? data : JSON.parse( data );
    this.data = this.data instanceof Array ? this.data  : [ this.data  ];    
  }

  Hmm.prototype.index = function( name )
  { //Name can have dots, 'car.tire.brand.name' should get the expected
    //Generates an index object 
    var index = {} , i;

    this.data.forEach( function( value )
    {
      var key   = getNamedValue( value , name ),
          keys  = key instanceof Array ? key : [key];
      for( i = 0 ; i < keys.length ; i++ ) 
      {
        key = keys[i];
        index[key] = index[key] || [];
        index[key].push( value );
      }
    });
    return index;
  };  

  Hmm.prototype.uniqueIndex = function( name )
  { //Create an index, point each index to the first of possible values
    var index = this.index( name );
    Object.keys( index ).forEach( function(key){
      index[key] = index[key][0];
    });
    return index;
  };

  Hmm.prototype.collect = function( name )
  { //Collect all the values for a given property name
    var values = this.data.map( function ( o ) {
      return getNamedValue( o , name );
    });
    values.unique = unique;
    return values;
  };

  Hmm.prototype.toString = function()
  { //More for jsbin than anything else
    return JSON.stringify( this.data );
  };

  return Hmm;

}());  

//Some tests

var foods = [

  { name : 'potatoes' , calories : 100 , allergens : [] , storage : 'ambient' },
  { name : 'pistachio ice cream' , calories : 1000 , allergens : ['nuts','milk'] , storage : 'frozen'  },
  { name : 'chocolate ice cream' , calories : 1200 , allergens : ['milk'] , storage : 'frozen' },
  { name : '2% fat milk' , calories : 600 , allergens : ['milk'] , storage : 'chilled' }  
];

var hmm = new Hmm( foods );

console.log( hmm.collect('name') );                 //Collect all names
console.log( hmm.collect('allergens') );            //
console.log( hmm.collect('allergens').unique() );
console.log( hmm.collect('allergens.0') );
console.log( hmm.collect('allergens.0').unique().sort() );
console.log( hmm.index('name') );
console.log( hmm.index('name').potatoes );
console.log( hmm.index('allergens').milk );
console.log( hmm.uniqueIndex('name') );
console.log( hmm.uniqueIndex('name').potatoes );
console.log( hmm.index('allergens') );
console.log( hmm.index('allergens.0') ); //Index on the first allergy
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very nice. What few qualms I have are a result of me looking really hard for things to have qualms about (furrowing my brow and going "hmm", basically).

Anyway, some thoughts:

- Your `unique` function relies on the assumption that there are no circular references in the object passed to `JSON.stringify`. It's probably a fair assumption, but an assumption nonetheless. Also, from a specification standpoint, JSON representation of objects doesn't impose or guarantee any ordering of properties. I *highly* doubt it'll ever be an issue anywhere, but it could mean that identical objects will have different JSON representations, and `unique` would thus include both those objects.
- Similarly edge-case'y: Your `instanceof` usage is vulnerable to [the usual cross-frame pitfalls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#instanceof_and_multiple_context_%28e.g._frames_or_windows%29).
- The `!~array.indexOf( value )` trick is a bit arcane. It's neat, but I don't think I've actually seen it used anywhere - except in some other code you posted :)
  A `=== -1` comparison isn't nearly as cool, but it wouldn't cause me to go "huh?". In other words: I like it, but I wouldn't call it obvious or idiomatic.
- That curly-brace-on-new-line style just rubs me the wrong way, but you know what you're doing, so I'll spare you the "automatic semi-colon insertion" speech :)

On a more overall note: Like jQuery, it might be useful to always return a `Hmm`-wrapped array, instead of only adding `unique` to the array returned by `collect`. Of course it'd be quite a different API.

Answer (score 4):

First off, a couple of your function names are slightly misleading/go against naming conventions in other libraries.

- `{hmm}.index` seems to be more of a [`group`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) function than a index finder.
- `{hmm}.collect` appears to be a [`pluck`](http://laravel.com/api/function-array_pluck.html) function but I've heard it called `collect` as well so \o/
- `{hmm}.uniqueIndex` should, imo, be called `groupFirst`

---

Alright, with that out of the way lets talk implementation

I think it would be useful for `Hmm` to inherit from `Array` as a pure wrapper - most of what you can do with an array you can do with an `hmm` instance (at least in modern browsers see [Subclassing Javascript Arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3261587/1517919).

This would just involve refactoring your code a little:

```
var push = Array.prototype.push;
function Hmm( data ) {
  //data could be a string -> treat as JSON, parse it
  //data could be an object, or a string that got converted to an object -> convert to array
  //data could be an array ( original or through conversion ) -> leave as is
  var _data = data instanceof Object ? data : JSON.parse( data );
  _data = _data instanceof Array ? _data  : [ _data];
  push.apply(this, _data); //merge with this hmm instance
}

Hmm.prototype = [];
// ....
```

Disclaimer: this may be too clever and might not work in some environments :)

Next, you can decide if you want to rewrite `map`, `filter`, et al to produce a `hmm` rather than an `array`

Another advantage of doing this is you can define `unique` on `hmm.prototype` so

`Object.keys(hmm.collect('allergens.0')) != ["0", "1", "2", "3", "unique"]` which I would consider a bug.

---

Other stuff

Seeing you seem to be writing for modern environments anyway I would write your constructor logic

```
var _data = typeof data !== "string" ? data : JSON.parse( data );
this.data = Array.isArray(_data) ? this.data  : [ this.data  ];
```

If you want to convert `Array-likes` (such as a `hmm` or `jQuery` instance) to `hmms` I would use the `underscore` check [see this issue for some discussion](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/1590):

```
var _data = typeof data !== "string" ? data : JSON.parse( data );
this.data = _data && _data.length === +_data.length ? this.data  : [ this.data  ];
```

You may also want to consider catching the `JSON.parse` - if it fails wrap the string in the `hmm` object, however that may lead to weird edge cases.

I might come back to his later as I need to take off. Last thing as has been mentioned, you're not a hacker -- no need for `!~array.indexOf( value )`.. `array.indexOf( value ) < 0` is the same number of bits and faster